# Initial cards are the same when using UICollectionView Yalantis/Koloda

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, koloda

I'm using this library and I am able to display my data from Firebase on to the cards. However the initial cards (3 default) are all the same. Then once I swipe them I can see the next results. This seems to be only the case when I am displaying a CollectionView on the card instead of just a UIView.

Here is how I fetch data:

```
var person: Person!

func fetchUser() {

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            guard let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot else { continue }

            let person = Person(from: snapshot)
            self.person = person
            PersonManager.shared.addPerson(person)
        }
        self.kolodaView.reloadData()

    })
}
```

Here is how I assign the data to the cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let person = PersonManager.shared.persons[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = person.firstName
    return cell
}
```

`PersonManager` is a singleton that handles the `Person` object and has the `append()` and `removeAll()` function.

And here is my result:

[image]

Has anyone got it to work properly with a tableView or collectionView?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that index in koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int) is valid. It seems you have used one index for all images.